# Field inside a conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics, conductors

[image]

If the above image is a cross section of a conductor, the field at the point shown is not zero. So the field inside a conductor is not zero at all points.

You could argue that the electrons would rearrange themselves so that the field inside is zero. But if that were true, all the positive charges would not be on the surface. For example, in the diagram above, the electron at the point shown, would move, leaving a charge in the centre.

What am I missing?

## ***I am not looking for a proof that the field inside a conductor is zero. Please address the problem I discussed above.***

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The positive charge on your conductor is gonna spread over the entire surface, not concentrate at two points. And yes, any field would cause the electrons to rearrange themselves such that the field is zero and the result of that is that all the charge is at the surface.

Comment: You assert that the diagram represents the actual distribution of charges and claim that this represents a problem, but you have not shown that the arrangement you propose is physically consistent as a steady state arrangement. And *that* is the problem: what you propose is *not* a steady-state arrangement of charges in a conductor. Note that the claim is (and has always been) only true in the steady-state (if your sources haven't mentioned that, then they have been cheating to simplify the explanation). Transient fields can and do exist.

Comment: @SpiderPig The positive charges *is* only two points. The positive charge is -2e, where e is the charge of a proton. Theres a deficit of two electrons in the conductor.

Comment: @dmckee What's a steady state? No source I have come upon mentions anything about "steady states".

Comment: Now, I think I see what you are getting at. You're thinking about *exactly two* electrons being missing and trying to reconcile that with the "evenly distributed" claim and finding this hard. Well, classically you *can't* reconcile it. The subject you want is quantum-mechanics as applied to condensed matter. The charge distribution in a good conductor is not a classical thing, the conduction electrons *can* spread out such that the excess positive charge is uniformly spread across the surface.

Comment: There are many cases in physics where you just have to agree to accept something for a while, so that you can go ahead leaning the skills and tools it will take to prove the thing you are asked to accept. In other words, lying to the student is a necessary part of teaching physics. Personally, I like to admit to the lies up front, but opinions on that vary.

Comment: "Steady state" many a condition in which things are not changing in time (or at least changing slowly enough that you can ignore that change for whatever purposes you have in mind). That is, the State of the system is steady. See? *::elbow nudge::* Get it, get it?

Comment: @dmckee Yes, I do. Thanks a lot, it cleared a lot of things up. If you post your comment as answer, I'll be glad to accept it. :)